# How can I change the whole look of a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I want to change the look of the whole JTextField but still want it to be editable. The first picture shows a normal JTextField, the second picture shows, what I want it too look like. So basically it is just a blue horizontal line instead of a whole Box.

[image: This is what the JTextFields look like normally:]

[image: But I want it to look it that way:]

I tried to override the paintComponent() method of the JTextField and draw a blue line with the Graphics object, but it didn't show any effect. Thanks for any help and sorry if this question does not fit the rules of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a custom border on the JTextField or overriding [paintBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintBorder(java.awt.Graphics)) instead

Comment: Did work for me, painting only MatteBorder with bottom line. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can override paintComponent(), just as you've said. Here's snippet for JTextField in simple JPanel:

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JTextField textField = new JTextField() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.drawLine(10, getHeight() - 10, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 10);
            }
        };

        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        textField.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        textField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        add(panel);
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
```